# How to write a function instead of a for loop using date ranges

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I'm a law professor new to empirical research and to R.  I'm studying whether a judge's workload (as the number of cases he/she completes in say 30 days) or his/her case backlog (as the ratio of cases opened to cases closed within the same range) affects case outcomes.  Some sample data:

```
# first generate a vector of dates and repeat it 4 times
beg.date <- rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2008-01-01"),as.Date("2013-12-31"),by="day"),4)
length(beg.date) # 8768
length(beg.date)/4 # 2192 dates (6 years)
# generate a vector of judges of same length
x <- factor(LETTERS[1:4]); judge <- rep(x, each=2192)
# cbind them as df
data <- cbind.data.frame(judge, beg.date)
# create end date exactly 30 days later for each case
data$end.date <- as.Date(data$beg.date + 30)
#sort by beg.date and add caseid variable
data  <- data[order(data$beg.date),]; data$caseid <- 1:8768
#reorder columns
data <- data[c(4,1,2,3)]
# reorder rows by judge and by end dates
data <- data[order(data$judge, data$end.date),]
```

Here's what the data look like:

```
  caseid judge   beg.date   end.date
1      1     A 2008-01-01 2008-01-31
2      5     A 2008-01-02 2008-02-01
3      9     A 2008-01-03 2008-02-02
4     13     A 2008-01-04 2008-02-03
5     17     A 2008-01-05 2008-02-04
6     21     A 2008-01-06 2008-02-05
```

So I want to calculate what the judge's 30-day backlog and completion rate were on the day the case was adjudicated.  I've figured out how to create the date interval (window) and to determine the number of cases that started or ended within that window.  And I'm able to apply it on a rolling basis over the data set by judge **using a clunky `for loop.`**

```
a <- data
comprate <- numeric()
ratio <- numeric()
for (j in c("A","B","C","D")){
  x=a[a$judge==j,]
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  y <- new_interval((x$end.date[i]-ddays(30)),x$end.date[i])
  x$comprate[i] <- length(x$end.date[x$end.date %within% y==T])
  x$ratio[i]  <- length(x$beg.date[x$beg.date %within% y==T])/x$comprate[i]
  }
comprate  <- append(comprate, x$comprate, after=length(comprate))
ratio  <- append(ratio, x$ratio, after=length(ratio))
}
a$comprate <- comprate
a$ratio <- ratio
```

This works on the small sample data set, but my project data has over 6 million observations (cases).  I know there is a way to do this with `ddply` or `dplyr` but it is just beyond me.  Can some one help me out?

Many Thanks. Ken

**Some Follow up questions:**

---

Thanks @MrFlick for the helpful answer.
Let me see if I understand (or please help me understand) how the solution works:

```
dt[, comprate:=sapply(end.date, function(i) 
    sum(between(as.numeric(i)-as.numeric(end.date),0,30))), by=judge]
```

In this codeblock:
1 the comprate variable is created by applying the `sapply(etc.)` expression `by=judge`.
2 `sapply` applies the `function(i)` to each element of `end.date` and returns the simplified result.
3 `function(i)` takes as its input the first element of `end.date`, `sum` returns the sum of the logical true values of the logical vector `between(etc.)`.

I'm OK I think up to here, but after this i'm confused about how `between` works and exactly which values are being included and evaluated.  So what exactly is `as.numeric(i)-as.numeric(end.date)` doing?  I get the `as.numeric` part -- it is just extracting the integer that represents the number of days after the sentinel date.

So 'as.numeric(i)' is extracting the integer value of the `i-th` element of `end.date`?
Then what is `- as.numeric(end.date)` doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't feel too bad, these moving window problems are a bit tricky.

Given the magnitude of your data, I might suggest using the `data.table` library. This library allows you to index your data such that lookups should be quicker. Here we do

```
library(data.table)
dt<-setDT(data)
setkey(dt, judge, end.date)
dt[, comprate:=sapply(end.date, function(i) 
    sum(between(as.numeric(i)-as.numeric(end.date),0,30))), by=judge]

setkey(dt, judge, beg.date)
dt[, newcase:=sapply(end.date, function(i) 
    sum(between(as.numeric(i)-as.numeric(beg.date),0,30))), by=judge]

dt[, ratio:= newcase/comprate]
a<-as.data.frame(dt)
```

So we use `setDT()` to turn `data` into a data.table object. Then we set the key which adds an index to the table. Next we use the special data.table syntax to add new columns. Here, for each judge, we calculate the number of end.dates in the last 30 days. It appears you used `lubridate` before. Here, since Date values are stored as the number of days since a sentinel date, i just convert to numeric and do the subtraction myself. Then I re-order and calculate the number of new cases. I do one extra step to calculate the ratio. Then I convert things back to a data.frame (but you could just as well keep them as a data.table).

So on this sample data it runs much faster and gives the same results. This does mean potentially leaning new syntax for a new package, but you should be rewarded with faster results.

---

Further explanation

So let's work with a simple vector

```
x<-c(1,3,6,9,10,15)
```

we can thing of these as dates in the numeric form. When we do

```
sapply(x, function(i) i-x)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    2    5    8    9   14
# [2,]   -2    0    3    6    7   12
# [3,]   -5   -3    0    3    4    9
# [4,]   -8   -6   -3    0    1    6
# [5,]   -9   -7   -4   -1    0    5
# [6,]  -14  -12   -9   -6   -5    0
```

What we are doing is taking each value of `x` one at a time (as `i`) and finding the difference to every other value in `x`. Each `x` value generates one of the columns above. Now i can add the between to see if the differences are between, say, 0 and 10.

```
sapply(x, function(i) between(i-x, 1, 10))

#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

So we use `between` (from the `data.table` package) to limit the results to a particular window in the past. Now, instead of returning a column for each `x` value, we take the `sum()` of the between values which will turn all TRUE values into 1 and FALSE into 0

```
sapply(x, function(i) sum(between(i-x, 0, 10)))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the generous answer.  I'm sorting it out now. And learning a new set of skills.

Comment: I'm OK I think up to a certain point (see my followup questions in my original question). But after this i'm confused about how `between` works and exactly which values are being included and evaluated.  So what exactly is `as.numeric(i)-as.numeric(end.date)` doing?  I get the `as.numeric` part -- it is just extracting the integer that represents the number of days after the sentinel date.  

So 'as.numeric(i)' is extracting the integer value of the first element of `end.date`?  
Then what is `- as.numeric(end.date)` doing?

Comment: @kmayeaux I've added some further explanations and a simple example to show more clearly how it works.

Comment: many thanks for the lesson.  So the speed improvement is in doing this as a matrix rather than scanning through each element of `end.date` to see if it is in the interval and then adding up the T's -- and then repeating that for each value of `end.date`?

Comment: Really, the speed improvement comes from using `data.table` which is able to do this operation more quickly by indexing the data. The description above is really about why you would expect those function to work. The actual implementation of how they execute may be different in the `data.table` calls themselves.